# how to extract data from responce of http.post in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

How i can get array data from - **resLogin.data** ?

```
then(function (resLogin){
                 $scope.response = resLogin.data;    
                console.log("From app.JS \n");
                console.log($scope.response); // true from table status
```

[image]

Comment: Please solve the notices in your webservice first (line 32 and 34 in login.php) or set the log level of the webservices to a lower level

Comment: these are of checkboxes there isn't any issue of them

Comment: echo json_encode($userDB)."\n";
         echo json_encode($mobileDB)."\n";
         echo json_encode($locationDB)."\n";
         echo json_encode($biodataDB)."\n";
         echo json_encode($passwordDB)."\n";

Comment: It clearly is an issue as the notification messages end up in `$scope.response`. So, solve that issue and then you will be able to retrieve the data by `$scope.response[0]`, `$scope.response[1]`, etc. Better option would be to let your webservice respond with JSON code. Makes it possible to get the vars by name.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vtcj5oxcakjri3/notices%20resolved.jpg?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vtcj5oxcakjri3/notices%20resolved.jpg?dl=0 ----- notices issue resolved,  and by using service iam getting data from server side and used in app.js after json_encode, now as you said if i am getting data as $scope.response[0], $scope.response[1] it is showing letters on indexes -- https://www.dropbox.com/s/922dhry7cdifa5v/letter%20isssue%20responce%5B0%5D.jpg?dl=0

Comment: answer please @JanP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create JSON serverside with something like:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('user' => $userDB, 'mobile' => $mobileDB, 'location' => $locationDB, 'biodata' => $biodataDB, 'password' => $passwordDB);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Now your response will look like:

```
{
    "user": "awais",
    "mobile": "12345",
    "location": "johar",
    "biodata": "...",
    "password": "..."
}
```

Each field can be retrieved by `$scope.response.user`, `$scope.response.mobile` etc.

Comment: I'm glad I could help